# .val with invalid value on select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I  have a `<select>`, and on button click users can select the next option:

```
$(".someButton").on('click', function () {
   var $opt = $("select :selected");

   $("select").val($opt.next().val());
});
```

The problem is that on the last option, `$opt.next().val()` returns some unselectable value, and apparently jQuery selects the *first* option by default.  What I would like is for it to stay on the last option.

Is there any way to do this (preferably without checking the position of `$opt` or the length of `$opt.next()`)?

Comment: Do you really need to rely on the value? If not, what about using `$("select option:selected").next().prop("selected", true)` instead?

Comment: @pimvdb Joseph Silber stole your answer (probably not on purpose), but if you make an answer for this I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a more efficient way to do it:

```
$(".someButton").on('click', function () {
   var el = $("select")[0];
   el.selectedIndex = Math.min(el.selectedIndex + 1, el.length - 1);
});
```

---

If you want to stick to jQuery, set the `option` to selected:

```
$opt.next().prop('selected', true);
```

If `$opt` is the last one, `.next()` will return an empty set, so nothing will change.

Answer (score 1):

I would just handle the case to be honest. It would be simple to add the following:

```
if(!$opt.is(':last-child')) {
    $("select").val($opt.next().val());
}
```

Comment: They really don't need to re-select the last value, so maybe something like `if(!$opt.is(':last-child')) { $("select").val($opt.next().val()); }` and that's it

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure if it was affecting multiple selects which is why I wrote it like that, I'll update answer though